# Есть ли такая форма слова — достан?

Tags: причастия, краткое-причастие

Можно ли слово *достать* употребить в форме ***достаный*** или ***достан***?

Как, например, *вынутый* или *вынут*

> Эта сумка *достана* из комода

Comment: https://glosum.ru/?act=sphinx&q=%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C&x=0&y=0